# hover testing not working on react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library

Testing opacity while hover button is not working. Tried with both `userEvent.hover(hoverButton)` and `fireEvent.mouseOver(hoverButton)` unfortunately the result is same. At the same time the other properties are working, for example `'cursor:not-allowed'`

**Button.js**

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ButtonWrapper = styled.button`
  color: #fff;
  background-color: tomato;
  font-size: 14px; 
  padding: 6px 30px;
  height: 35px;

  &:not(:disabled):hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    background: red;
  }

  ${({ disabled }) =>
    disabled && `
      opacity: 0.4;
      cursor: not-allowed;
    `}
`;

  // background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.buttonColors[props.kind]};

const Button = ({ children, className, disabled, size = 'medium' }) => {

  return <ButtonWrapper
    className={className}
    disabled={disabled}
    onClick={() => console.log('Hello mate')}
    size={size}
  >{children}</ButtonWrapper>;
}

export default Button;
```

**Button.test.js**

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import Button from './index';

test('should render button', () => {
  render(<Button>Click on me</Button>);
  expect(screen.getByText(/Click on me/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});

test('should render disabled button', () => {
  render(<Button disabled>hover on me</Button>);
  const hoverButton = screen.getByRole('button');
  
  expect(hoverButton).toBeDisabled();
  expect(hoverButton).toHaveStyle('opacity: 0.4')
  expect(hoverButton).toHaveStyle('cursor:not-allowed')
});

test('should hover button', () => {
  render(<Button>hover on me</Button>);
  // const hoverButton = screen.getByRole('button');
  const hoverButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'hover on me' });
  
  userEvent.hover(hoverButton);
  // fireEvent.mouseOver(hoverButton)

  expect(hoverButton).toHaveStyle('opacity: 0.8')
  expect(hoverButton).toHaveStyle(`background-color: #000`);
});

test('toMatchSnapshot', () => {
  const { asFragment } = render(<Button>Click on me</Button>);
  expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

I found a few obstacles that you're running into:

1. There's a mistake in the test, where the `background-color` was expected to be `#000` when it's set as `background: redu` in the `Button.js` file.
2. I'm pretty confident that the testing-library's `hover` interaction doesn't update the computed styles. I verified this using [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) in the DOM versus in the test. That said, you can use [jest-styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-styled-components#tohavestylerule)' `toHaveStyleRule`, to check for pseudo styles however that's not really not going to cover what you're attempting to test.
3. Currently, there's really no way for you to test a button's current appearance based upon a browser interaction, unless that interaction add/removes styles dynamically using some sort of React state or prop (similar to what you've done with `disabled`). As a result, there's no way to accurately determine it's appearance since every `Button` has the same pseudo styles (the snapshots showcase this, but also looking at the DOM will showcase the same [thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpGwn.png)):

```
exports[`Button disabled snapshot 1`] = `
<DocumentFragment>
  .c0 {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: tomato;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 6px 30px;
  height: 35px;
  opacity: 0.4;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.c0:not(:disabled):hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: red;
}

<button
    class="c0"
    disabled=""
  >
    Click on me
  </button>
</DocumentFragment>
`;

exports[`Button enabled snapshot 1`] = `
<DocumentFragment>
  .c0 {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: tomato;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 6px 30px;
  height: 35px;
}

.c0:not(:disabled):hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: red;
}

<button
    class="c0"
  >
    Click on me
  </button>
</DocumentFragment>
`;
```

#### Recommendation:

You don't need to test against native interactions/style changes with the DOM. Instead, test against what you do control. In this case, you're controlling whether or not a button can be disabled and appending styles based upon that prop. Other than testing that (which you've already done), in this case, any other tests should be considered ancillary/superfluous.

Taking a step back, what exactly are you trying to test? It seems like  you are trying to test if a browser can apply a style via a specific CSS selector to a button? This seems rather unnecessary, no?

#### Not recommended:

This will test if an element contains a particular pseudo style, but again, it's shared and there's really no way to determine when its styles are active (even if you added a `disabled` button prop, this test will still pass because it still contains the pseudo styles!):

```js
test("should contain button hover styles", () => {
  render(<Button>hover on me</Button>);
  const hoverButton = screen.getByRole("button");

  expect(hoverButton).toHaveStyleRule("opacity", "0.8", {
    modifier: ":not(:disabled):hover",
  });
  expect(hoverButton).toHaveStyleRule("background", "red", {
    modifier: ":not(:disabled):hover",
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanations. I was trying to test that the hover effects `opacity` working or not. The test gives background value at the same time `opacity` not getting in the `toHaveStyle`